# Creating continuous arrays through a for loop iteration in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am attempting to create an array that is continually added onto as I loop through multiple csv's. The current code that I have creates multiple arrays within an array, but I would like it to be one continuous array. In the end, I would like the have the DT_temp with its corresponding type_id in a dataframe. Any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this?

```
import glob 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
path = ** my folder path 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.csv") 
type_id = []
DT_temp = []
for filename in all_files: 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, header = 0)
    
    type_id.append(df['type_id']) # type_id = a distinct number
    df_temp = df[['unix_time_stamp','temperature']].dropna()
    DT_temp.append(df_temp['unix_time_stamp'].diff())
DT_frame = pd.DataFrame(type_id) 
DT_frame['TimeDiff_Temp'] = DT_temp
```

Comment: Could you please be more descriptive with what each variable is and which variables you are referencing in your description?

Comment: `np.array(alist)` can convert a suitable list of arrays into one array.  `np.concatenate` may also be used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.